# Stacked bar chart in Chart.js where not every bar has the same number of elements

Tags: chart.js

I am using Chart.js to build a stacked bar chart to show sales data of software products. The stacked bars represent the two different kinds of licenses we sell: full licenses or upgrade licenses. Not all products have an upgrade license though, and this is where the problem comes in.

I have my sales data in the following format:

```js
const product_variant_sales = {
  "Product One": { Full: 234, Upgrade: 987 },
  "Product Two": { Full: 456, Upgrade: 895 },
  "Product Three": { Full: 3456 },
};
```

So for product three we only sell a full license, not an upgrade license (since it's at version 1).

I am using the following code to turn this data into a dataset:

```js
const products = Object.keys(product_variant_sales);
const variants = ["Full", "Upgrade"];
const product_variant_sales_datasets = variants.map(variant => {
  return {
    label: variant,
    data: products.map(product => {
      return product_variant_sales[product][variant] ?? 0;
    }),
    backgroundColor: `rgb(38,96,137,${variant === "Full" ? 1 : 0.8})`,
  }
});
```

And the resulting bar graph looks great!

[image]

However, there is a problem. When you hover over one of the products that doesn't have an upgrade license, it does show it as 0 sales:

[image]

This is misleading. We didn't have zero sales of the upgrade license.. there simply is no upgrade license. How can I have a stacked bar chart where not every bar has the same number of elements? Since the data arrays in both datasets need to have the same number of elements, I can't just leave them out. I tried replacing `?? 0` with `?? null` and `?? undefined` but that didn't do anything either.

For good measure, here's my chart code:

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById("product_sales"), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: products,
    datasets: product_variant_sales_datasets,
  },
  options: {
    interaction: {
      intersect: false,
      mode: 'x',
      position: 'nearest',
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        stacked: true,
        border: {
          color: "#254b5d",
        },
        grid: {
          color: "#254b5d",
        }
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true
      }
    },
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to hide the label when the value is `null`, like so:

```js
function productsChartLabel(context) {
  if (context.raw === null) {
    return null;
  }
  return `${context.dataset.label}: ${context.formattedValue}`;
}
```

And then in the plugin options I added this:

```js
tooltip: {
  callbacks: {
    label: productsChartLabel,
  }
}
```

This solves my problem. I do find the datasets a bit annoying to work with though, where I have to give 2 arrays of equal lengths instead of an array of objects which represent the stacks, but it is what it is :)